# Отправить POST на Robokassa

Tags: php, mysql, post

**Старая логика сайта:**

1. Услуги: пользователь выбирает тариф >
2. Оформление заказа: вводит логин и почту >
3. Детали заказа: в бд отправляем информацию о заказе и предлагаем её проверить пользователю. Страница обернута `<form action="https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/Index.aspx" method="post">` со скрытыми инпутами для Robokassa. При нажатии на кнопку "Оплатить" - отправляем post и пользователя на сайт Robokassa для оплаты. Всё ОК.

**Решил отказаться от одного шага и вот, что получилось:**

1. Услуги: выбор тарифа и ввод логина >
2. Детали заказа: показываем информацию о заказе и просим ввести почту

**И тут возникла следующая проблема:** до того, как пользователю открылась страница "детали заказа" - в БД можно добавить всё, что и раньше, кроме почты, которую пользователь ещё не ввел. Но когда он её введет и нажмет на кнопку оплатить, то его форма сразу отправит на Robokassa, поэтому я решил изменить на `<form action="" method="post">`, отлавливая данные `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`  и записываем в БД всю информацию с почтой, но **как** теперь **отправить пользователя с POST данными в Robokassa?**

P.S. Можно конечно перейти на GET и тогда, через header() без проблем сделаем редирект, но хочу остаться на POST, т.к. не люблю открыто отправлять данные. Добавить ввод почты на странице "услуги" не могу, не позволяет дизайн.

Comment: По моему почту можно передать скрытым полем в робокассу, а потом когда робокасса будет стучаться на result.php прочитать ее и записать в бд. Но не уверен.

Comment: Пришел к такому решению: убрать вообще почту, т.к. пользователь её введет на сайте Robokassa, а после уже оттуда забирать её. Меньше препятствий - выше конверсия, что на коммерческом сайте весьма важно. )

Answer (score 2):

Пришел к такому решению: убрать вообще почту, т.к. пользователь её введет на сайте Robokassa, а после уже оттуда забирать её. Меньше препятствий - выше конверсия, что на коммерческом сайте весьма важно.